# Show Combobox selected item in textbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, combobox, selecteditem

```
Public Class Form1
Public selected As Integer

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Select Case ComboBox1.SelectedItem
        Case "Philippines (PHP)"
            selected = 1.0
        Case "United States(USD)"
            selected = 45.2
        Case "Japan(JPY)"
            selected = 0.36
        Case "Canada(CAD)"
            selected = 35.01
        Case "Australia(AUD)"
            selected = 33.34
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    TextBox1.Text = ComboBox1.SelectedItem
End Sub
End Class
```

please dont laugh i am just casually reading basic tutorial in VS2010..
my problem here is nothing from the selected item in combobox shows in the textbox..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your 'selected' variable is the wrong type. It needs to be a string or a double type. String if it's just going to be used for readability and double if you intend on using it in a calculation.

```
Public selected As Double

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    ' Call the ToString() method to get the text.
    Select Case ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
        Case "Philippines (PHP)"
            selected = 1.0
        Case "United States(USD)"
            selected = 45.2
        Case "Japan(JPY)"
            selected = 0.36
        Case "Canada(CAD)"
            selected = 35.01
        Case "Australia(AUD)"
            selected = 33.34
    End Select
    ' You need to catch if the selected variable has not value set.
    Textbox1.Text = selected.ToString()
End Sub
```

Comment: well that fix it.. but now my concern is im making a 2nd combobox with the same variables and add the value all together and to show it on the textbox1

Answer (score 2):

1st `selected` is an `int` so it cant have values like 1.0,45.2,etc.
2nd, TextBox1_TextChanged is not fired, so try like this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
 ...
 TextBox1.Text = ComboBox1.SelectedItem
```

Comment: Plus 1 for the integer catch

Answer (score 0):

This is c# code but I'm sure the concept is the same. Your TextBox1_TextChanged event is never being triggered because you are never setting the text of the textbox so that can be removed, and move that code into your comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged event.

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
        {
            case "Hey":
                selected = 1;
                break;
            case "There":
                selected  = 2;
                break;
            case "You":
                selected  = 33.34;
                break;
        }
        textBox1.Text = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
```